# Some transactions dated as 1970

Tags: chaindata

I am currently analyzing ethereum data from google big query and and some transactions are dated as being from 1970-01-01. I assume that has to do with how date is stored since it is in seconds from 1970. Was wondering if anyone has come across this?

Currently work around would be to replace to when ETH was launched. However, there are a number of these transactions so not sure this is the best way to deal with the issue.

Comment: Can you please give an example (preferably as a link to etherscan.io)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean traces, not transactions.  There are 8893 traces with zero timestamp (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) that correspond to 8893 initial balances hardcoded into Ethereum Genesis block.  You may see them on [Etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io) as well: https://etherscan.io/txs?block=0
Note, that these “transactions” are not real ones.  They do not have hashes and you cannot see their details.

Comment: Thank you, yes that is correct I am looking at traces instead of transactions. Because when I was only looking at transactions some wallets had negative amounts of money in them. Do you recommend any resource to better understand traces?